# Network profile not showing up when connecting to a Link local. E.g. USB Ethernet gadget

Tags: networking, windows-10, raspberry-pi, network-adapter, network-profiles

When I make my Raspberry Pi Zero W an ethernet gadget and connect it to the computer.

It shows up as an unidentified network. This causes there to be no network profile on the RNDIS/Ethernet adapter set up by the Raspberry Pi. Is there a way in windows or on the raspberry pi so that it does not report has an unidentified network?

I would like the Raspberry Pi to report itself has an identified network so that I can use the network profile. This would allow me to set the network has private. As of right now, I have to set all unidentified networks has private.

Can this be done using the built-in config files and dhcpcd server in the Raspberry Pi? I don't want to have to load in a full DHCP on the PI just to get the name of a network. A Raspberry Pi solution would be ideal. Is there some domain name setting that I can use to make this work.

This is related to a larger project [Hardware monitoring using a Rasberry Pi on a local connection](https://www.mod-bros.com/en/forum/t/using-rndis-ethernet-to-connect-raspberry-pi-zero-to-computer-network~926)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows apparently calls calls any network an "unidentified network" if it doesn't have a gateway.

The Adafruit instructions you were following (https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget), if you only followed the basic instructions and not the advanced ones, make your Raspberry Pi Zero W show up like a USB Ethernet adapter dongle that's connected to an isolated Ethernet switch with only a Raspberry Pi attached to it (no gateway). Your Windows box and your Raspberry Pi both get IPv4 link-local addresses (169.254.x.y/16), just like would happen if your connected your Windows box to a network that didn't have a DHCP server. Link-local addressing doesn't provide a gateway address, so Windows calls it an unidentified network.

The instructions you were following tell you how to fix this, under the heading "Advanced Networking (Fixed IP)". You use your Raspberry Pi's local config files to give it a static IP address, and you give your Windows box a static IP address (including a gateway address) on the same subnet on that USB Ethernet adapter interface, and then you unplug and re-plug your USB cable to get Windows to recognize that it now has a gateway address on that interface so it counts as an identified network.

Comment: I had set the static IP the way it is shown in the guide but It did not work. I had to set the default gateway to the IP of the Pi on both the Pi and the computer. This is the opposite of what the Adafruit guide did. Once i used the raspberry pi has the default gateway Ip it worked. Thank you!